# Setting iCal Calendar defaults

Tags: macos, ical

I have a calendar with birthdays in them and I'd like to set the repeat to "Every year" -- unfortunately setting each manually seems quite painful. Would there be an easier way to accomplish this?

Im on an OSX 10.8.

Answer (score 1):

You could add the birthdays to your Contacts, then you'll see each birthday every year automatically.